# I made a function for selection sort, and I can't figure out what's going wrong here

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, selection-sort

I made a function for selection sort, and I can't figure out what's going wrong here.

```
void selection_sort(int n,int *arr){
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
  
            if(arr[j]<arr[i]){
                int temp=i;
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[temp];
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing that's going wrong is that this appears to be bubble sort. The second thing is that instead of `int temp=i;` you meant `int temp=arr[i];` and instead of `arr[j]=arr[temp];` you meant `arr[j]=temp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find a picture to help. Here’s a good graphic I created some time ago:

[image: Selection Sort Animation]

This is what your code should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

In your `selection_sort()` function:

```
if(arr[j]<arr[i]){
    int temp=i;
    arr[i]=arr[j];
    arr[j]=arr[temp];
}
```

`arr[temp]` is `arr[i]`, and since you assign `arr[i]` with the value of `arr[j]`, `arr[j]=arr[temp]` is just `arr[j] = arr[j]` So this code just assigning `arr[i]` with the value of `arr[j]`.

Use `std::swap()`:

```
if(arr[j]<arr[i]){
    std::swap(arr[j], arr[j]);
}
```

Also, the logic appears to be bubble sort, not selection sort.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the value of actual iterate element in temp varaible. What you are actual do, is save actual iteration number-1 in temp variable.

```
void selection_sort(int n,int *arr){
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(arr[j]<arr[i]){
                int temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void selection_sort(int n,int *arr){
int min_ix;  //minimum element index
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)  {
    min_ix = i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
          if(arr[j]<arr[min_ix]){
            min_ix = j;
            swap(arr[min_ix],arr[i]);          
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The code snippet use had provided was for bubble sort and this one's for selection sort.

selection sort: repeatedly finds the minimum element to sort an array
bubble sort: repeatedly swaps the adjacent elements if they are in wrong order.